# Want to show some content on just home page

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website it has some code in **header.php** which I want to display only on the home page:

```
<header id="header">
     <!-- few lines of code displaying Images and some text -->
</header>`
```

I tried to put this line but it is showing some error

```
<?php if(is_front_page())
```

Comment: try `is_home()` http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/when-to-use-is-home-vs-is-front-page

Comment: What's the error, can you post it? you can try `is_home()` but if you use a static front page that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
<?php if (is_home()): ?>
    <!-- ... -->
<?php endif; ?>
```